# Помогите решить проблему

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, list

Я решаю задачу по **Python** на codewars.
Подробнее ознакомиться с ней вы можете [здесь](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5266876b8f4bf2da9b000362/train/python).
Я написал код для решения этой задачи и запустил на сайте.
Но он не работал из-за определенных ошибок.
Вы можете сами это увидеть на картинке ниже:

[image]
Но когда я запускал тот же самый код у себя на компьютере, никаких ошибок не было.
Вот сам код:

```py
names = [
    "Alex", "Jacob", "Mark", "Max"
]

liks = {
    'Alex': 'like',
    'Jacob': 'like',
    'Mark': 'like',
    'Max': 'like',
}


def like(list_names):
    for i in names:
        print(
            'likes [{}] // must be {} {} this'.format(i, i, liks[i])
            )
like(names)
```

В чем проблема? Как это исправить?
И каким еще способом решить эту задачу?

Comment: Вы объявили функцию “like”, а в задании просят сделать функцию “likes”

Answer (score 1):

Тестировщик CodeWars вызывает функцию likes, она должна вернуть результат, её в твоем коде нет.

Comment: Было хорошо , если бы скинул силку на это задания

Comment: Так я скинул ссылку на задание. Посмотрите выше

Comment: Да. Я сейчас понял это. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Если ещо актуально (за минуту накидал):

```py
def likes(names):
    obj = ' likes this'
    obj1 =' like this'
    if len(names) == 0:
        return 'no one' + obj
    elif len(names) == 1:
        return ' '.join(names) + obj
    elif len(names) == 2:
        return ' '.join(names).replace(' ',' and ') + obj1
    elif len(names) == 3:
        return names[0] + ', ' + names[1] + ' and ' + names[2]  + obj1
    elif len(names) >= 4:
        return names[0] + ', ' + names[1] + ' and ' + '%i' %(len(names) - 2) + ' others' + obj1
```